# Identify all unicode characters that could use diacritical marks, with macOS APIs

Tags: ios, swift, macos, unicode, nsstring

For an optimized search function I'm using, I need to identify any characters in a Unicode string that can potentially be modified with diacritics.

For example, the characters "a", "U", "e" and "n" can use diacritical forms as in "ä", "Ü", "é", "è" and "ñ". How can I build such a list of all these chars? Either statically or dynamically?

Effectively, I like to end up with all characters that are affected by the "diacritics insensitive" options for string comparisons, like they're used by `[NSString stringByFoldingWithOptions:NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch]` and by the `[cd]` (and `[d]`) options of `NSPredicate`.

### Targets

I'm doing this on macOS, for a native app, so any native framework function or 3rd party lib I can freely add to my app would do. I also tagged iOS, because I'm quite hopeful that what's available on iOS will also work on macOS.

### Background with example, for those who need to understand

I need this in order to be able to search in a data pool that provides a search function that is diacritics sensitive, and which contains *precomposed* unicode characters.

Consider this data set (no, it's not a common database, so forget about suggestions in that direction):

- Fisch
- Flügel
- Fraktur
- Fräulein
- Frau
- Französisch
- Fleisch
- Flamme

I can query this database only by fetching each entry one by one, with the *option* of pre-filtering the returned items based on a case-insensitive, normalization-insensitive but diacritics-sensitive sub-string comparison.

Now, I want to find all entries that contain the sub-string "Frau" with diacritics-insensitive lookups, i.e. I want to find both "Frau" and "Fräulein" in the data set.

The easiest way would be to query EVERY entry in the data set (i.e. without a filter) and then perform comparisons using macOS' string functions that provide diacritics insensitive lookups. I could even speed up the comparison loop by prefolding the search string and the prefold every queried item. But that's insignificant. I just want to explain that I know what I'm doing here.

The query operation is rather expensive (think of a network connection over which the results are returned, i.e. the slow network is the bottleneck). For that reason, the fewer items it needs to return, i.e. the better I pre-select the result with said filter, the better performance I get. **And that's the reason for this question.**

To make this work, I filter on "Fr" (or "fr", since the filter is case-insensitive). This will give me these results back:

- Fraktur
- Fräulein
- Frau
- Französisch

Then I can perform my previously mentioned own comparison on top of these items to find the ones I was looking for.

So, by pre-filtering the results, I can significantly speed up my search. To make this work, I need a way to reduce the search string to a set of contiguous characters (ideally the longest of those) for use with the data set's filter function, making sure I won't cause it to remove items from the result just because it uses a different diacritical mark than expected.

Comment: You are going to the wrong way. For searching, you should use Unicode Compatibility Normalization, which take care of your problems, and a lot others

Comment: So if the user types `"Fraul"` how would you match `"Frl"`?

Comment: @LeoDabus Why do you think I'd want to match "Frl" when I search for "Fraul"? I wonder if I explained my task not well enough.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi No, you apparently do not understand my situation. I stated that I am bound to use a certain function that does not support diacritics-insensitivity. Please accept that and don't tell me to go around that, which I simply can't. If I need to find an "ä" than I cannot pass "a" to that function to find the "ä". Therefore, I need to remove that char from the search in order to it not limit the matching for these unpredicatable chars.

Comment: So use the the Canonical Normalization. An accent could be written in several ways, e.g. as a single character, or as a character and an accent (things are more complex if you have more "combining marks", which it is not seldom, especially if you consider accent + mark under a letter). Note: the last case has nearly infinite possibilities (fonts will merge marks). For the first, just look canonical decomposition (decomposition field in UnicodeData.txt in UCD, and remote compatibility [which have a `<`]. You may filter with Scripts.txt for unwanter scripts.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I know what canonical normalization is. That's not helping because the data I am searching is already in its own state and I cannot change it. So, when the data contains a word with "ä" in _precomposed_ form, then I cannot find it unless I explicitly search for it - I cannot find it by searching for "a".

Comment: I told you how you can build the list, directly from Unicode Database: Decomposition field (and you take only the canonical decomposition). With GC field you can filter just the diacritics (which they are the very most common case). So you have a list of derived characters from a selected base character. I do not understand why **internally** you cannot normalize (Compatibility must used only internally, per Unicode standard), but if you want to go with the complex way. Just the list above is very large (in base char, but also ever list per base char).

Comment: And thinking it more. I think Unicode, or W3C published also that list. I do no remember the context. But it was an ugly list.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi I've updated my question with a concrete example. Also, you originally wrote that I should *search* using Normalization, which won't work in my case. Now you suggest I can build my table from it. Yes, that's what is what my actual question is about: How do I build that table? I cannot do it brute-force, that would be too complex (I'd have to check every code point and combine it with any known diacritics modifier - I don't even know how to learn about all those!).

Comment: I googled before to find such a list but had no luck. Now, with all the buzzwords in these comments, I tried again and found this: http://pinyin.info/unicode/diacritics.html - I'll see if that helps. If you care to get credit for your help, please write an answer mentioning it, and I'm happy to mark it. The problem, however, is that this list includes almost every ASCII char (all but Q, V, X), which means I hardly have anything left for use in my filter. Sigh. I'd have to make it locale-specific

Comment: You may check also this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57169516/get-all-unicode-variations-of-a-latin-character